# "A Token was not found in the SecurityContext" on Silex / Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I built a Silex project with an login mechanism.

Not being a Symfony expert, I strictly followed the guidelines here for the authentication process : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html

... and it works fine on my development environment

However, when I pushed my project on my production server, I get the following error each time I try to log into my web app

```
[2012-12-18 16:35:33] CRITICAL: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException:
A Token was not found in the SecurityContext. (uncaught exception) at
/my/app/path/vendor/symfony/security/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php line 53 [] []
```

which means that the following code in AccessListener.php

```
$this->context->getToken());
```

throws an expection

Given the fact that the same code works perfectly fine on my development environment, I assume it has something to do with my production server configuration.

I found this thread http://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony-devs/jKphNy_0Q2Y/vYfkAuyjSHEJ that suggests to add the following line to my project's .htaccess

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

with no result. I still get the "A Token was not found in the SecurityContext" exception.

Does anybody have an idea ?

**Edit**
The content of `$app['security.firewalls']` is the following

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
'security.firewalls' => array(
'login' => array(
  'pattern' => '^/login$'
),
'admin' => array(
  'pattern' => '^/',
  'form'    => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/login_check'),
  'logout'  => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout'), // url to call for logging out
  'users' => array(
  'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', 'SOMEPASSWORD'),
  ),
)
)
));
```

Comment: can you post settings of `$app['security.firewalls']` array?

Comment: @m2mdas : I've included it above

Comment: Try adding `'anonymous' => true,` in the `login` firewall array.

Comment: What webserver are your running?

Comment: It could be that the security context of symfony2 could be written in a SQLite database (don't know about silex, but could be similar). Anyway, make 100% sure that all file permissions on your prod server are set correctly.

Comment: @m2mdas : I've added the setting, with no changes

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz : thanks for your reply but what kind of file permissions should I check ?

Comment: Please post the complete .htaccess in your question

Comment: Do sessions work for you? The error may be coming from not being able to save session data (though you should get an error saying this). Also: can you provide a minimal silex project as a github gist that replicates your problem? I have both apache and nginx available to experiment.

Comment: @benoit Can you please provide the data that [Michel Feldheim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1032504/michel-feldheim) asked for in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14302533/1339429). We are just trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems it has nothing to do with HTTP Basic Auth, because you don't use it in any of your firewalls. What you use is a firewall with a `form` entry point, which then uses session to store the security token.

I would suggest you to look at how sessions (and cookies) are managed on prod server compared to your dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the reason why this works on your local machine but not in your productive environment is that .htaccess is supported by Apache, while [nginx does not bother wasting I/O and CPU time parsing this files](http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess)

If you post your .htaccess I will show you how to translate this to performant nginx-readable configuration.

**EDIT**

Silex even has a configuration example for nginx

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html

Comment: Check out the link I added above